# Datatables.net add row not work

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I use the composant jquery datatables.net.
I Create my table, but when  I would like add row 'manually', The row is not added at the end of the table.
I see that after add table row, my console.log(data) in Render 'Email' display '123' but the row is not added.

My code javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $select = $('<select id="selectoption"></select>');
    var $checkbox = $('<div class="container"></div>');
    var $input = $('<input type="text">');
    var $span = $('<span></span>');
    var table = $('#griduser').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip',
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/User/ReadUserTest/",
            "dataType": "json"
        },
        columns: [
            {"data": "Delete"},
            {"data": "Id",
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    var $clone = $span.clone();
                    $clone.attr("id", "userid");
                    $clone.append('<label>' + data + '</label>');
                    return $clone.wrap('<span></span>').parent().html();
                }
            },
            {"data": "UserName",
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    var $clone = $input.clone();
                    $clone.attr("id", "userid");
                    $clone.attr('value', data);
                    return $clone.wrap('<div></div>').parent().html();
                }
            },
            {"data": "Login",
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    console.log(data);
                    var $clone = $input.clone();
                    $clone.attr("id", "userlogin");
                    $clone.attr('value', data);
                    $clone.val(data.Login);
                    return $clone.wrap('<div></div>').parent().html();
                }
            },
            {"data": "Email",
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    var $clone = $input.clone();
                    $clone.attr("id", "email");
                    $clone.attr('value', data);
                    $clone.val(data.Email);
                    return $clone.wrap('<div></div>').parent().html();
                }
            },
            {"data": "Save"}
        ]
        ,
        "columnDefs": [
            {"targets": -1,
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": "<input type='image' id='saverole' src='/images/save.png' alt='Submit' width='48' height='48'>"
            },
            {"targets": 0,
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": "<input type='image' id='saverole' src='/images/remove.png' alt='Submit' width='48' height='48'>"
            }
        ],
        "initComplete": function (settings, json) {
            table.row.add({
                Delete: 'delete123', Id: 'id123', UserName: 'name123', Login: 'login123', Email: 'email123', Save: 'save123'
            }).draw();                
        },
    });
});
```

Json data is:

```
{"sEcho":null,"iTotalRecords":2,"iTotalDisplayRecords":2,"aaData":    
[{"Id":"09b90bca-7bf5-4956-91c9- 0d7cee180ba5","UserName":"nouveau@test.com","Login":"nouveau@test.com","Email":" nouveau@test.com"},
{"Id":"86f9eabd-ec1e-40b1-af5b- fea899d4c1c0","UserName":"nouveautest@test.com","Login":"nouveautest@test.com"," Email":"nouveautest@test.com"}]}
```

And my html code is:

```
<table id="griduser" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>Login</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>Login</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Thanks for your help

Update:

Error with oninitcomplete:

-in javascript qjuery.datatables.js(line 2022):

```
var aoData = oSettings.aoData[ iDataIndex ];
if ( aoData.nTr === null )
{
_fnCreateTr( oSettings, iDataIndex );
}
```

-in console.log error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nTr' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an object / literal as this

```js
table.row.add({
   Login: '123', Email: '123', Id: '123', Save: '123', UserName: '123'
}).draw();
```

Is correct *if* you have defined the proper `data` bindings in `columns`, as you actually have done above. However, you *must* at least have the same properties in the object you are about to insert as you defined in `columns`. dataTables will look for each `data` binding in the object, and fail to insert if some properties are missing. `Delete` is missing from the object :

```js
table.row.add({
   Delete: 'something', Login: '123', Email: '123', Id: '123', Save: '123', UserName: '123'
}).draw();
```

should work.

Comment: I use your code but now row is added. If I change Datatables with 'datatables' I have an error. I try add render of my column data and save like others but it's not work. I defined the columns save and delete because I need to add a button to this cell

Comment: @Zoners - besides you have an error in your JSON, `" Email"` should be `"Email"` - and under assumption that the code you have provided actually is the code you are using, then it works -> **http://jsfiddle.net/cuwpmwmr/** I guess the reason you _now_ experiencing regarding `add()` is due to javascript asynchronicity. The table is not finished initialising before `table.row.add()` because you are using serverside data, but it will work if you later on `add()` upon clicking a button etc.  Proof it by placing `table.add` in a [initComplete](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete)

Comment: Sorry, I was on holiday :).  I accept your answer because the demo work.  But I try used "initComplete", I see all my field is complete and after the function initcomplete is call, I use table.row.add but I have always the error " .I update my post original

Answer (score -1):

the add funtion takes a list in parameter not a dictionnary, use

```
 table.row.add([
        'Login Value','Email Value','Id Value', 'Save Value', 'UserName Value'
    ]
     ).draw();
```

Using that method, the values need to be in the same order as the table columns. This exemple assumes that your table looks like this:

```
__________________________________________________
|--login--|--email--|--id--|--save--|--username--|
```

EDIT

With the html code, i can see you have 6 columns, when you add the row, you should define a value for each column like so:

```
table.row.add([
    "", "09b90bca-7bf5-4956-91c9- 0d7cee180ba5", "nouveau@test.com", "nouveau@test.com", "nouveau@test.com", ""
]
 ).draw();
```

Comment: I have this error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Login' of undefined' and it's possible change render when I add a row?  I update my post with example json and html

Comment: If I use your last response not row added and not pass in the render but if I use this "        table.row.add({
            Login: '123', Email: '123', Id: '123', Save: '123', UserName: '123'
        }
         ).draw();" the row is not added but we pass in the render

Comment: Is anything displayed in the table? Or, it fails only when you try to manually add a row? Is there any error in the console when you use  table.row.add({ Login: '123', Email: '123', Id: '123', Save: '123', UserName: '123' } ).draw();?

Comment: nothing is displayed in the table and nothing display in the console :s it's not easy to understand where is the problem

Comment: Just a quick guess, there is two constructor for datatables. Theres "Datatable()" and "datatable()" (notice the lowercase d). Try the constructor with the lowercase 'd'.

Comment: Your code is not correct, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30582198/3549014) for explanation why.